# (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address xx.xxx.xx.xx:80

Tags: linux, apache, fedora-core

I'm trying to add a virtual server in apache:

```
Listen xx.xxx.xx.xx:80
NameVirtualHost domain.com
<VirtualHost domain.com>
DocumentRoot /home/webserver/domain/html
ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

when I restart apache I'm getting this error:

```
(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address xx.xxx.xx.xx:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

any idea what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you aren't starting apache with the right permissions (only root can open port 80), or something (probably another apache) is already running on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the additional network cards were not configure with the addition IP's.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted so that the question doesn't come up as unresolved. Thanks.